# JQuery validation only works on the first generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I'm trying to resolve this issue but no matter what I try (based on several suggestions solutions found here as well), I can never make it work.

I would like the Jquery validation plugin to validate automatically all the generated fields from a form. My problem is that it will only work on the first generated field; the validation of the subsequent ones will just be a duplicate of the first.

Here's the pertinent html code:

```
<form class="someFormClass" method="post">                     
<span>
    <input class="calendarName" name="description" value="<?= value_from_php ?>">
    <input class="calendarName" name="description" value="<?= value_from_php ?>">
</span>                                 
</form>
```

And here's the jQuery validation code:

```
$(function () {
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        rules: {
            description: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "calendar/calendar_available/",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        name: function () {
                            return $(".calendarName").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            description: {
                required: "Description field can't be blank !",
                remote: "This calendar already exists."
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So, as stated, the plug-in behaves properly for the first field. But if I check the values posted in Chrome's Network, the "name" key created in the jQuery validation will always send the value of the first input.

I tried many things (trying to implement on more level of ".each" method in the validation, trying to generate dynamically a specific id for each field to point on (instead of a class), trying to modify the plugin code as suggested here ([How to validate array of inputs using validate plugin jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670447/how-to-validate-array-of-inputs-using-validate-plugin-jquery)), but it didn't work.

I think there's something I don't grasp about the logic here.

**UPDATE :**
So, one of the reasons of my problem is that jQuery validation absolutely requires input with different names. See : [Jquery Validation with multiple textboxes with same name and corresponding checkboxes with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404191/jquery-validation-with-multiple-textboxes-with-same-name-and-corresponding-check)

So, I made a script to generate a different name for each input with the intention to dynamically create validation rules based on those names, following this suggestion : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700420/3504492

My validation script now look like this :

```
$(function() {
var rules = new Object();
var messages = new Object();

$('input[name*=description_]:text').each(function() {
    var currentName = $("input[name="+this.name+"]").val();
    rules[this.name] = { 
            description: {
                required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "calendar/calendar_available/",
                        type: "post",
                        data: currentName
                        }
                    }
                },
            color: {required: true}    
    };
    messages[this.name] = { 
        description: {
                    required: "Description field can't be blank !",
                    remote: "This calendar already exists."
                },
        color: {required: "Color field can't be blank !"}
        };
});    

$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        rules: rules,
        messages: messages                
    });
})                });
```

This almost works. Almost because if I limit the rules et messages to the required keys, it will display the validation each field (if I add the specific name to the message string, it will display on the proper field). But with a most complex rule like mine (with a remote key containing various keys for instance), I get a " Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element , check the 'description' method." error in the Console.
My guess is that the "description" declaration in the "rules" definition should be dynamic too (the current "name" field being visited).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you really have a dot at the front of your className in the html?  If so, `$(".calendarName").val()` will likely be undefined

Comment: No, that's a copy/paste typo actually, it's not in my code. I'm editing it out. Thank you... :)

Comment: Do you have more input fields with class=calendarName?

Comment: Yes I do. It seems that could be the nature of the issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404191/jquery-validation-with-multiple-textboxes-with-same-name-and-corresponding-check

I tried following this solution, but it doesn't make a difference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24671026/3504492